# Writing interface for array of objects and with array included with same objects

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

Here is my array, i like to iterate: it has single object an array of object. how to write interface for it? how to replace `any[]` with appropriate declaration?

code :`

```
export const initialPhotoProps:any[] = 

[
  {
    urls: {
      sm: "/assets/mobile/model_front.jpg",
      lg: "/assets/desktop/model_front.jpg",
    },
    id: "model-front",
    alt: "Model front photo",
    caption: "mcdayen",
  },
  [
    {
      urls: { sm: null, lg: "/assets/desktop/model_back.jpg" },
      id: "model-back",
      alt: "Model back photo",
      caption: "mcdayen",
    },
    {
      urls: { sm: null, lg: "/assets/desktop/model_back.jpg" },
      id: "model-back",
      alt: "Model back photo",
      caption: "mcdayen",
    },
  ],
  {
    urls: { sm: null, lg: "/assets/desktop/model_back.jpg" },
    id: "model-back",
    alt: "Model back photo",
    caption: "mcdayen",
  },
];
```

`

```
export interface PhotoProps {
urls: { sm: string|null; lg:string|null}
id: string;
alt: string;
caption: string;
}
```

`export const initialPhotoProps: PhotoProps[]` - but throws error from array section. how to mix and write the interface?

Need the interface to mix both object and array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your array allows both `PhotoProps` and an array of `PhotoProps` as valid elements, you have use a union of `PhotoProps | PhotoProps[]` to type the array resulting in `(PhotoProps | PhotoProps[])[]`.

```
export const initialPhotoProps: (PhotoProps | PhotoProps[])[] = [
  /* ... */
]

export type PhotoPropsArray = (PhotoProps | PhotoProps[])[]
```

---

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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)

Comment: How to export this union interface to other files?